# Import Excel spreadsheet into Access from a form

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I want to import spreadsheets that are all the same format.

It is a data entry database.

The data is entered on many client computers (there is no network) and then imported into one.
The exported filenames may vary so I want the end user to be able to import the files one by one, but can select a different named file from the dialogue box.
I have been trying to get the filename data_entry.xlsx to be wild cards.
I have tried dimming as a string, but then you have to give the string an actual filename.

The following code imports a file Data_entry.xlsx if it is found, then opens a dialogue box where the user thinks they can choose a file of any name and import it. In fact the import has already occurred.

The software is used on a remote Pacific island where IT support is not great or I would use the import spreadsheet feature of Access.
Instead I want the database to allow the end user to browse for the Excel spreadsheet of any name and import it.

```vb
Private Sub Command4_Click()

Dim ffx As Object

Set ffx = Application.FileDialog(3)

'Dim fileName As String

ffx.AllowMultiSelect = False

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Data_entry_import ", "data_entry.xlsx", True, "b1:s9000"

If ffx.show = True Then
    MsgBox "Success!"
Else
    MsgBox "No file was imported"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the filename, the user has selected:

```vb
Private Sub Command4_Click()

    Dim ffx         As Object
    Dim FileName    As String
    Dim FolderName  As String

    Set ffx = Application.FileDialog(3)
    ffx.Title = "Select Excel file to import"
    ffx.AllowMultiSelect = False
    ffx.Filters.Clear
    ffx.Show

    If ffx.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        ' User cancelled.
        MsgBox "No file was imported."
    Else
        FileName = ffx.SelectedItems(1)
        FolderName = Left(FileName, InStrRev(FileName, "\"))
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Data_entry_import ", FileName, True, "b1:s9000"
        MsgBox "Success!"
    End If        

    Set ffx = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, do rename `Command4` to something meaningful.

Comment: Thank you so much - that worked.      I so wish I had asked earlier.  I would not have got it by myself.  and yes will rename command4 - it was just like that while I tried to figure it out.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.

Comment: I would but how to mark the question as answered is not really obvious.    This is my first post - do I mark it on this page or in my account - I have looked in both.

Comment: Ah it is ok - it is the Tick on the left - I think